# Python modifying CSV data

Tags: python, csv

I have a file which looks like this(i.e random combination of 2 /3 consecutive rows) :

```
String A
String B
String C
<Blank Row>
String D
String E
<Blank Row>
String F
String G
String H
<Blank Row>
String I
String J
String K
<Blank Row>
String L
String M
```

I want the output file to remove the middle row when there are 3 consecutive rows and transpose the 2 remaining row. IN case there are only 2 rows, they should be transposed. The final result should look like this.

```
String A,String C
String D,String E
String F,String H
String I,String K
String L,String M
```

Any pointers how to get this done?

Comment: Any code you have written so far? (Please post it; since SO is not a coding service, your question, as written, is off-topic.)

Comment: One line: `'\n'.join(['{},{}'.format(l[0],l[-1]) for l in [b.splitlines() for b in f_in.read().split('\n\n')]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `count` from `itertools` module along with `list comprehension`.

This answer is a little hacky, but do the trick. See the comments for better understanding the logic behind.

I'm assuming that your input, is the input you gave in a file called `my_input_file` and your output file is called `output_file`:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

# Read the file and split by the space between Value and its number
# Leave the case where the empty string '' exists without splitting its spaces
with open("my_input_file", 'r') as f:
    data = (k.split() if k != '' else k  for k in f.read().splitlines())

# Group the fields splitted, which are lists, in data
# And separate them by the field where the string 'Blank' exists 
sub = [list(v) for _, v in groupby(data, lambda x: isinstance(x, list))]

final = []
for elm in sub:
    # if the lenght of the grouped elements is > 1
    if len(elm) >1:
        # Convert the number of the values into an int
        # For further calculations
        dd = map(lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1])], elm)

        # Group the consecutive numbers of elem
        for _,v in groupby(dd , lambda x,y=count(): x[1] - next(y)):
            # If there is a consecutive numbers
            bb = list(v)
            if len(bb) >1:
                # Conveert them into strings. Then, append the first and the final one to the final list
                final.append(' '.join(map(str, bb[0])) + ',' + ' '.join(map(str, bb[-1])))

            # If there is'nt any consecutif numbers. Append the element to the final list
            else:
                final.append(" ".join(map(str, bb[0])))


# create the output file
with open("output_file", 'a') as f:
    for k in final:
        f.write(k + '\n')
```

This code will output a file which contain:

```
Value 1,Value 3
Value 4,Value 5
Value 6,Value 8
Value 9,Value 11
Value 12,Value 13
```

Test this code and leave your feedbacks if you have any, or maybe, please report bugs if you found any of them.

**Edit:**

According to your last edit.

If your input file is:

```
What Test 
Makes No Sense 
is This 

My name 
Is Sample 123 

Your Name 
is ABC 2134 

What is you 
technical question don't know 
name?
```

The trick, is so simple. You can do something like this, using only `groupby` from `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open("my_input_file", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()

final = [list(v) for _, v in groupby(data, lambda x: x != '')]

with open("ouput_file", 'a') as f:
    for k in final:
        if k != ['']:
            f.write(k[0] + ',' + k[-1] + '\n')
```

And, your output file will be:

```
What Test ,is This 
My name ,Is Sample 123 
Your Name ,is ABC 2134 
What is you ,name?
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , The <Blank Row> us not a string but actually a blank space. I have updated the question to reflect the output in a better way.I am getting the following error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'STRINGVALUE'"

Comment: dd = map(lambda x: [x[0], int(x[1])], elm) seems to be the issue , that may be because of the way I have phrased the question .

Comment: You're editing a lot your question ! :/ keep calm and add how your file is. The second value is a string, an int or what ?

Comment: It is just a string : ABC DEF

Comment: a string like this `'1'` or `'a'` ?

Comment: String looks llike 'a'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145837/discussion-between-misguided-and-chiheb-nexus).

Answer (score 0):

In order to rotate: you know all lines have a new line at the end

```
with open("PATH TO FILE.txt", r) as file:
    input = file.read()
    input.replace("\n", "")
```

for the lines that only have white spaces, or to identify them. SO far:

```
   with open("PATH TO FILE.txt", r) as file:
        input = file.read()
        if not line.strip():
           input.replace("\n", "")
```

and you can keep a count or do a while loop so you count until you hit the line with only white spaces and while counting put each line in a list or something,
if you counted 3 grab the first and the third, otherwise grab both. Remember to reset the count